# opening and closing or ports using Gstreamer

Tags: java, sockets, gstreamer

i'm trying to develop an `RTP proxy server` and have completed it half way. I have a `rtpbin` from where I can send the files to the remote host. But now my supervisor - says that - A method should be implemented to open and close sockets (socket management) which needs to be done using Gstreamer and the code should be in java only.

A part of my code is as under

```
        //send data over network via udp 

    Element udpSink_rtpout = ElementFactory.make("udpsink", "udpsink0") ; 
    udpSink_rtpout.set("host", REMOTE_HOST) ; 
    udpSink_rtpout.set("port", 5000) ;

    // rtpL16pay - payload encode raw audio over rtp packets
    Element rtpL16pay = ElementFactory.make("rtpL16pay", "rtpPay") ;
    //  rtp part ends here

    // add all elements into a pipeline 
    pipeline.addMany(source, demuxer, decoder, conv, rtpL16pay, rtpbin, udpSink_rtpout) ;

    // link all elements  
    Element.linkMany(source, demuxer) ;
    Element.linkMany(decoder, conv, rtpL16pay) ;
    // link to rtp 
    logger.info("Linking pads ....") ;
    Element.linkPads(rtpL16pay, "src", rtpbin, "send_rtp_sink_0") ;
    Element.linkPads(rtpbin, "send_rtp_src_0", udpSink_rtpout, "sink") ; 

    demuxer.connect(new PAD_ADDED() {
        public void padAdded(Element element, Pad pad) {
            logger.info("Dynamic pad added, linking demuxer/decoder") ; 
            Pad sinkPad = decoder.getStaticPad("sink") ;
            Element.linkPads(element, pad.getName(), decoder, sinkPad.getName()) ; 
        }
     });

    // set the pipeline to playing state
    logger.info(" pipeline now playing....and ") ;
    pipeline.setState(State.PLAYING) ; 
    logger.info(" Pipeline state is " + pipeline.getState()) ; 

    loop.run() ;
    logger.info(" returned ..stopping playback") ;
    pipeline.setState(State.NULL) ;      
   }
 }
```

Can anyone let me know how do I add a method now for opening and closing of sockets using JAVA?

Comment: In what way do you need to create a socket? Would this be a manually created socket for your udpsink? [Here is the GSocket struct in glib](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GSocket.html) which gstreamer uses and you can create and set manually

Comment: Hello Benjamin Trent, I am trying to build a RTPproxy server and for this I think its required that the sockets are created and deleted automatically. Please can u help me in creating a rtp proxy server and am really a newbie and struggling a lot in it. please

Comment: You can listen on a `udpsrc` element and send out like you are currently doing over a `udpsink` element. Gstreamer automatically creates sockets with those elements.